# Determining the equilibrium points in a difference equation

Tags: reference-request, recurrence-relations

I have been given a difference equation:
$$x_{t+1}  = a\cdot x_t\cdot(1-x_t)$$
and I want to find out the equilibrium points of the system.
Could you recommend something to read in order to solve this problem?

The only thing I would know is to set $x_{t+1}= x_t$.

**How do I solve this ?** :(

Comment: You can find a lot of fascinating properties of this iteration by searching for "Feigenbaum map". It's one of the classic examples of how chaotic behavior emerges from regular behavior under continuous parameter changes.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yeah i already saw that. and i know that it has one (stable) solution for a<1 and so on ... but i want to proof it mathematically. How do i proof it ?

Comment: As to "how do I solve this," what's mysterious about a (barely) quadratic equation?

Comment: Maybe a further question : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map#Behavior_dependent_on_r    .How do we know, these different behaivors for a ? There is also a proof, which i don't understand : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html

Comment: @AndréNicolas can you write down the quadratic equation, i have to solve ? ... maybe i'm just tooo blind to see it :(

Comment: If you have stability, $x_{t+1}=x_t$; use that to get your quadratic equation.

Comment: @fragant1996:  taking your idea of setting $x_{t+1}=x_t$ and using $x$ for the variable, you have $x=ax(1-x)$ or $ax^2+(1-a)x=0$ with solutions $x=0,\frac{a-1}{a}$

Comment: $x=ax(1-x)$, or equivalently $ax^2 -(a-1)x=0$, with the solutions $x=0$ and $x=(a-1)/a$ (if $a \ne 0$).

Comment: @RossMillikan thanks .. now i understand

Comment: May I suggest that someone promote a comment to an answer? Brian, Ross, Andre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x=ax(1−x)$, or equivalently $ax^2−(a−1)x=0$, with the solutions $x=0$ and $x=(a−1)/a\ $ (if $a≠0$)

Thanks @André Nicolas and @Ross Millikan